# Which quandles arise as knot quandles

Tags: knot-theory

Is it known which quandles arise as the knot quandle of some knot? I seem - vaguely - to remember hearing that all (finite?) quandles arise this way but I've failed to find a reference to this fact.

Comment: Personal anecdote, John Stallings showed me the initial knot quandle paper, showing that the quandle did a wonderful job of classifying knots. His comment was that there were plentiful imponderables, such as deciding whether a prescribed quandle was trivial. 

Comment: what is a quandle?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racks_and_quandles
$$ $$ 


Comment: @Will-Jagy, so a quandle has to have both the right-distributive and the left-distributive properties of a rack, along with having $a\triangleright a=a$ and $a \triangleleft a = a$?  Is the matrix-form the best way to represent it? (sorry to be asking another question as a comment...)

Comment: Each knot quandle is connected.